# DAO pattern with Lists

Tags: java, sql, design-patterns, dao

I'm working on an application with two objects called Types and Tags.

**Type.java**

```
public class Type {
    private String name;
    private final UUID uuid;
    private final List<Tag> tags;
}
```

**Tag.java**

```
public class Tag {
    private String name;
    private final UUID uuid;
}
```

**Tables.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE tag (
  tag_uuid CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  name     VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE type (
  type_uuid CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  name      VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE type_tags (
  type_uuid CHAR(36),
  tag_uuid  CHAR(36),
  PRIMARY KEY (type_uuid, tag_uuid),
  FOREIGN KEY (type_uuid) REFERENCES type (type_uuid),
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_uuid) REFERENCES tag (tag_uuid)
);
```

I'm following the DAO design pattern, but I'm having trouble applying it here. Each Type can has a list of Tags, so what's the best approach to load a Type?

Comment: I suggest that you use an IDE such as Eclipse and use their built-in tools to generate the Entities and DAO's.  It will automatically take care of the `One-Many` relationships

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?  You may use SQL joins;  You may load the type first, and issue another SQL to find alll tags.  These are all very intuitive way.  Any problem with these approach?